# How to send Array thru .post in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, serialization

Here is my code that does not work:

```
var sessionListJSON = GatherSessionsFromPage();

    $.post('ajax.php', {
        _ExportMissingAddressesToXLS : 1,
        sessions : sessionListJSON  // ARRAY
    }, function(data) {

    });
```

here is my `php` attempt to catch it:

```
else if (array_key_exists('_ExportMissingAddressesToXLS', $_POST)) { // {{{
    $sessions = $_POST['sessions'];
    ExportMissingParentAddressesToXLS($sessions);
} // }}}
```

How do I properly send this array through this `jQuery` `.post` and then retrieve it in PHP?  Also, would this be a case of serialization?  If so, how do you do this for JS/jQuery?

Comment: If it's JSON, then it's already serialized -- that's what JSON is all about.

Comment: And if it's an array, it's confusing to put `JSON` in the variable name.

Comment: Try to put var_dump($_POST); before any conditions in ajax.php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery automatically serializes arrays for you in `$.post()`. In PHP, `$_POST['sessions']` will be an array if `sessionListJSON` was an array. You can access it with ordinary array indexing, `foreach`, etc.

If `sessionListJSON` is really a JSON string, you need to decode it in PHP:

```
$session = json_decode($_POST['sessions']);
```

Comment: yup, this was it.  I had it in my mind I was passing an array but I had it in my mind that it was an array.  I guess it's just along JSON string

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion when working when any complex data structure being passed between javascript and PHP would be to use JSON serialization/deserialization and not rely on `$_POST` behavior at all.

This may look like this in javascript/jQuery.

```
var json = JSON.stringify({
   _ExportMissingAddressesToXLS : 1,
    sessions : sessionListJSON  // ARRAY
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json', // if you expect JSON in return
    data: json,  // your JSON string here
    success: // your success handler
    error: // your error handler
});
```

On the PHP-side, since you are not dealing with form-encoded data, you would need to read PHP's raw input.  Luckily this is very simple and converting the POST data into a PHP object/array is very trivial.  It is as simple as this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$variable = json_decode($json);
```

Note that with default `json_decode()` behavior you would actually get an object that you could work with like

```
if($variable->_ExportMissingAddressesToXLS === 1) {
     $sessions = $variable->sessions;
     ExportMissingParentAddressesToXLS($sessions);
}
```